# How does a for loop know to increment

Tags: python, for-loop

When defining a Fibonacci sequence the following code was used:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    current=0
    after=1
    for i in range(1,n):
        current,after=after,current+after
    return after
```

How does the for loop know to increment by one every time we pass through? I tried using a while loop `while e<=n:` and it returned an error as I hadn't defined `e`.

Comment: The trick here is that the loop does not increment, it only iterates over a list. `range` generates a list with the numbers from `1` to `n`.

Comment: You _could_ use a `while` loop here, but you'd have to define `e` before the start of the loop and increment it yourself inside the loop, so it's simpler just to use the `for` loop. Note that your  `for` loop doesn't actually use the value of `i`, but that's quite ok. Some Python programmers would write it like `for _ in range(1,n):` to signify that the loop index variable isn't being used in the loop body. BTW, your function isn't quite right: it should return 0 for `fibonacci(0)`.

Answer (score 3):

A for loop in python iterates through items or generators. In your example, `range(1,n)` will return a `list` of elements between `[1, n)` in python2, or a generator that will `yield` the same items in python3.

Essentially, a `for` loop can iterate any kind of *iterables*:

```
for item in [1, 6, 8, 9]:
    print(item)
```

It will print 1, 6, 8 and 9.

Using `range`, there is a 3rd optional parameter which allows you to specify the increment:

```
range(1, 10, 1)  # The defaut [1 .. 9] numbers
range(1, 10, 2)  # From 1 until 9 with 2 of increment
```

Answer (score 1):

### `for` loop does not increment, instead it iterates

The `for` loop does not increment, instead it is asking so called iterable to provide values to work with.

In your example, the iterable is `range(1,n)`.

In Python 2.x, the `range(1, n)` creates a list of values and the `for` loop is only asking the list to provide next value in each run, until the list gets exhausted from values.

In Python 3.x the `range(1, n)` is optimized and returns special iterable type `<range>`, which when asked by `for` loop to provide next value provide it.

Answer (score 0):

By default if you don't specify your step i.e for i in range (start,stop,step) the increment is considered as one otherwise it's your step that you specified.

Comment: True, but that's a property of the `range` function; `for` doesn't know anything about that.